# How to tell the SD card version?

Tags: sd-card

As I understand, an SD card can be V1 or V2. Within the V2 catagory, there is non-SDHC and SDHC. I have an 1 GB SD card. Is there any software or anything that I can tell if it's V1 or V2?

Comment: Really? I thought SDHC only applied to 4gb for both versions.. you could have 4GB-SD and 4GB-SDHC, then everything above is SDHC and everything below 4GB is standard... Thats why if you want compatibility in SD cards, I always use 2GB or 1GB ones. Just think about, why would you use HighCapicity on 2GB, if it does not exceed the limit?

Comment: a) 4GB cards are always sdhc. b) the op is asking about some distinction between different kinds of non-sdhc card, which I'm unfamiliar with. Try to draw a Venn diagram if you're still confused.

Comment: I don’t suppose you are referring to *speed classes* are you?

Answer (score 2):

You must talk directly to the card to decide whether it is "SD 1" or "SD 2.x", either via SD protocol or SPI. Thouse USB->SD card readers hide this detail from you.

But it is of **no** interest for a user. I've looked through my code from a deeply embedded system - talks to SD/SDHC via SPI - and this bit is not used anywhere. So it contains zero usable information.